# Angular 15: NgRx store strictActionImmutability & strictStateImmutability errors

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am new to Angular and I got some errors due to the NgRx strictActionImmutability/strictStateImmutability checks, which are set to true by default.

I read some documentation, and to my understanding they verify the store's actions/states mutability.

Therefore, as suggested online, I edited my reducers by assigning the state cloned objects and also by dispatching clones to stores. Nevertheless, I still get errors ("cannot extend property X of object..") that disappear when I set the two checks to false.

I've also edited the selectors I made, in order to pass copied items, but I guess I'm missing something.

Could someone please list all the changes I need to implement to be compliant with the strictActionImmutability/strictStateImmutability?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you share in your post the code that creates this error?

Comment: @Wandrille thanks, I've just checked my code and noticed there were some operations left inside my reducers that triggered the error (the return {}; sintax that should be avoid). By removing it everything works fine now and I ll mark the question as resolved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I discovered some modifications left inside my reducers:

```
on(TreeActions.UpdateActiveItem, (state, {item}) => ({ 
   \some operations/
    return {
      ...state,
      treeItem: [...newItem]
    }
  }))
```

By removing the calculations and the return sintax everything works fine.